# P(XY<1/2) , X and Y uniform independent RV [-1,1]

Tags: self-study, random-variable, independence, joint-distribution

I think the probability should be equal to shaded area shown in the figure divided by 4, which is equal to (3+ln 2)/4. Is this correct, because my answer is not matching[image]

My solution:
I find the area and divide by 4 to normalise it.
First i find the quarter-circle looking area which is on top right & bottom left and subtract from area of square which is 4.

So area left out = $2 \int_{1/2}^{1} \int_{1/(2y)}^{1} dx dy  = 2(1-ln2)/2$. Therefore required answer = (4 - (1-ln2))/4 = (3+ln2)/4

Comment: It this a homework question? Please add the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then explain your derivation of the probability.

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: For what is worth, I think your derivation is correct. What is the answer you want to match?

Comment: the answer key says 0.85

Comment: Then I think the question is to find *P{|XY| < 0.5}* with *X* and *Y* uniform independent RV [-1,1].

Comment: Yep, that's a clever guess. Then answer would be (1+ln 2 )/2 = 0.846